# Package a Python app with Tide SDK doesn't work, while Launch App does

Tags: python, tidesdk

I have been working on an app for the Leap Motion, in Python, and when I tested it, it worked fine when I clicked Launch App. No app windows open, but the Python code all works fine.

However, when I package the app and launch that, it does show an app window and the Python isn't working at all... Am I missing something?

Here's the code of my index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            Titanium.include("PyLeapMouse.py");
            Titanium.include("Geometry.py");
            Titanium.include("Leap.py");
            Titanium.include("LeapFunctions.py");
            Titanium.include("Mouse.py");
        </script>
        <script type="text/python">
            import Leap
            import Mouse
            import LeapFunctions
            import time
            import sys

            def main():
                cursor = Mouse.cursor()
                listener = LeapFunctions.Listener(cursor)

                controller = Leap.Controller()
                print "Adding Listener."
                controller.add_listener(listener)#Attach the listener

                print "Press Enter to quit..."
                sys.stdin.readline()
                controller.remove_listener(listener)

            main()
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#1c1c1c;margin:0">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include has been removed from 1.3.1 beta version

https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-release

Comment: Oh poo... Thanks anyway, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try including your Python modules in the following manner:

```
<script type="text/python" src="PyLeapMouse.py" />
<script type="text/python" src="Geometry.py" />
<script type="text/python" src="Leap.py" />
<script type="text/python" src="LeapFunctions.py" />
<script type="text/python" src="Mouse.py" />
```

I know the global namespace changed from `Titanium` to `Ti` also, so if that doesn't work, you might want to try `Ti.include` versus `Titanium.include`.

Hope that works.

Comment: Neither of those worked, I'm afraid. I did discover that when I removed the Python import lines, it worked the same way after launching as it did after packaging: just showing a black screen but not working. Guess when you 'launch' an app, it handles the Python differently than after packaging it.